# Getting problem when installing manage package

Tags: portal

> 1. Missing Organization Feature: `PartnerNetwork`
> 2. Missing Organization Feature: `PRM`

I want to install a package but I am getting above error, I think it is related to partner portal if yes then how I can resolve this error.

I think portals is no more available and replaced by Community so How I can install this package.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 4):

A PartnerNetwork is part of Salesforce to Salesforce. You need to [Enable Salesforce to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=business_network_enabling.htm) in your org.

**Edit**

From the [Object Reference for Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm):

> **UserType:**
>
> **PRM:** user whose access is limited because he or she is a partner and typically accesses the application through a partner portal. Label is Partner.

In your situation, this would apply to a Partner from a PartnerNetwork related to Salesforce to Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks PartnerNetwork is a part of Salesforce to salesforce but I also want to know about Missing Organization Feature: PRM feature

Comment: See my edited ansswer

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the managed package you are trying to install requires your instance to have licenses for the 'Partner and customer community' feature. This is a paid-for feature available in Sales Cloud Enterprise edition and higher.

You would need to contact for sales representative at Salesforce to purchase licenses for this feature to complete the install.